# How to use values from a map

Tags: go

I want to use the values in the map I created to  multiply with the days that are given by the input.

I just don't know how to scan for the values that are stored in the map.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    typeCar := map[string]int{
        "audi":  50,
        "volvo": 100,
        "tesla": 300,
    }

    fmt.Print("how many days would you like to rent?: ")
    var days int
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &days)

    fmt.Println("the price is:", typeCar["audi"]*days, "euro")

    // "typeCar["audi"]" should be the input of the user instead.
}
```

Comment: Please take [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) to become familiar with the basic workings of Go.

Answer (score 1):

you can get user input as a string and test it against the map to retrieve the value associated.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    typeCar := map[string]int{
        "audi":  50,
        "volvo": 100,
        "tesla": 300,
    }

    fmt.Print("how many days would you like to rent?: ")
    var days int
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &days)

    // "typeCar["audi"]" should be the input of the user instead.
    fmt.Printf("waht type %v ? ", typeCar)
    var userInput string
    fmt.Scan(&userInput)

    tCar, ok := typeCar[userInput]
    if !ok {
        panic("not a valid car")
    }

    fmt.Println("the price is:", tCar*days, "euro")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over a map in go, use the range keyword

```
for key, value := range typeCar {
   //access values here
}
```

This will give you the key and value of that key in the map.